# PHP fckeditor problem?

Tags: php, fckeditor

How do I correct the following error that is listed below. I'm using PHP & MySQL.

I get the following error.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html was not found on this server.
```

I followed the directions on http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Integration/PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is caused by the wrong path to the fckeditor. i.e. the value of the `$oFCKeditor->BasePath` is wrong in your code. Because of this, the server generates a 404 error, because the file can not be found on the server.

By default, in the tutorial, it uses an absolute path relative to the host name. In otherwords, it expects the fckeditor to be in `www.example.com/fckeditor/`. However, if this is not the case for you, and, for example  your fckeditor is located in `www.example.com/mysite/fckeditor/`, then the value of the `$oFCKeditor->BasePath` should be changed to `/mysite/fckeditor/` instead. Also, make sure the capitalization is correct, if the server is UNIX based.